# How to query (sql) by listing the sports of the player doesn't belong to?

Tags: mysql, sql, lumen, relational-division

sports table

| id | sport name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | basketball |
| 2 | volleyball |
| 3 | golf |
| 4 | baseball |

players table

| id | sport name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | michael |
| 2 | stephen |

player sports table

| id | player_id (players.id) | sport.id (sports.id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |

**RESULT I WANT:**

Michael (id: 1)
should list the sports he doesn't belong to:

- (2) volleyball
- (3) golf

Stephen (id: 2)
should list the sports he doesn't belong to:

- (2) volleyball
- (4) baseball

This was the sql i did for Michael, but it return all data from playersports table including Stephen sports

```
SELECT * FROM `sports` LEFT JOIN `playersports` ON `sports`.id = `playersports`.sport_id WHERE `playersports`.`player_id` != 1;
```

Comment: `EXISTS(...)` or `NOT EXISTS()...)` , that is the question.

Comment: I am not rude. I'm just pointing you at the existance of `EXISTS(...)` [and: `in(...)` is often inferior]

Comment: You want this for every player or only one player at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude all sort_ids which belog to player 1

```
SELECT s.id,s.name
FROM sports s WHERE s.id NOT IN ( SELECT sport_id FROM player_sports WHERE player_id  = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! now i get the idea about NOT IN